# Help with linux kernel compilation script

Tags: bash, shell, linux-kernel

i wrote a script to compile the kernel:

```
cd /usr/src/linux-2.4.18-14custom
make bzImage
make modules
make modules_install
cd arch/i386/boot
yes|cp bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-2.4.18-14custom
cd /boot
yes|mv 2.4.18-14custom.img 2.4.18-14custom.img.back
mkinitrd 2.4.18-14custom.img 2.4.18-14custom
reboot
```

if i execute every line in the console it works, but when I put all of them in the script it executes only this 2 lines and ends:

```
    make bzImage
    make modules
```

any ideas to make it work?

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you running the script as root?

Comment: Try adding `set -x` to the top of the script.

Comment: Do you have a shebang line? You don't show it.

Answer (score 0):

#### kernel building

`make -C /usr/src/linux help` shows the options for building and installing a kernel.

- [initramfs](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Initramfs) allows for a built-in initrd equivalent that requires no post-build effort. I don't know if that's been backported to linux-2.4; but why 2.4?
- Use `make all install modules_install` to install everything. Maybe 2.4 Makefiles require a separate "modules" target too.

After switching to initramfs, it's likely everything can be accomplished with  one make command:

```
 make -C /usr/src/linux  all install modules_install
```

#### Scripts

For an example install script see *arch/i386/boot/install.sh*.  Also, seen the *Makefile* in that same directory to see how it all works.  If a system-wide [installkernel](http://linuxmanpages.com/man8/installkernel.8.php) script exists (*/sbin/installkernel* in Gentoo), or a user one $HOME/bin/installkernel, that'll be used.

The script originally posted with this question will work under the right conditions. I ran it; but faked mkinitrd, and skipped reboot.

- The script does not check for failure. It should stop if make fails, and not fail if the old fies for mv or cp don't exist.
- cosmetic: `yes|mv` and `yes|cp` should be replaced with `cp -f` and `mv -f`.  See the man pages (or `mv --help`, `cp --help`).